# Adding aspect to an abstract method?

Tags: .net, aop, postsharp

PostSharp gives this error:

> PostSharp: Cannot apply an
>   OnMethodInvocation aspect (...) with
>   target-site weaving on the abstract or
>   external method "...". Consider
>   excluding the aspect from this method
>   or use call-site weaving.

Suggested call-site weaving is not an appropriate solution for me. Is there any way to add pre/post processing for the abstract method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use aspect inheritance. The aspect will be automatically added to all methods implementing the abstract method.

See MulticastAttribute.AttributeInheritance or MulticastAttributeUsageAttribute.Inheritance, or [official documentation](http://doc.postsharp.org/1.5/##PostSharp.HxS/UserGuide/Laos/Multicasting/Inheritance.html) for details.

Comment: Looks like what I need, but it doesn't work correctly with OnMethodInvocation aspect. Any ideas? BTW, your documentation behaves very oddly in Opera browser.

Comment: OnMethodInvocation should work even with inheritance. Check with Reflector to understand what happens.

Answer (score 0):

This is of course imposible - how would you perform target-site weaving with an abstract method, a method without any code? You can of course perform target-site weaving with all  derived types implementing the method, but this requires that you control this types. Or you could make the method non-abstract and virtual and require derived types to call the base implementation.

Comment: There is at least one way to make it possible - use "template method" pattern. PostSharp already uses it for virtual methods. The same can be done with abstract methods.

Comment: "[...] way to add pre/post processing for the abstract method?" Do you mean performing some steps before or after a call in code? And what do you want to achieve with the aspect?

Comment: I just need to perform some code before and after each method from the specified group of methods. PostSharp seemed a good solution, but problem with abstract methods makes it impossible.